# How to hide URLS in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, curl

How to hide URL's in MYSQL but readable with curl and PHP? E.g. Obfucation or anything to hide those URL's.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Please clarify.

Comment: Basically hiding the url e.g. google.com. Making it not readable in MYSQL.

Comment: @Raymond hiding how? Please rephrase your question. It really doesn't make any sense at all right now. Maybe provide some examples.

Comment: I think he means encryption/decryption in which case... http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Comment: Maybe you want to store URLs in MySQL, but you don't want it to be obvious that they are, in fact, URLs? If so, I'd use symmetric encryption in PHP and store the encrypted URLs in the database, keeping the password somewhere in PHP (with the usual protections applied: make it readable to the www-data user and nobody else). I don't see why you'd want to hide URLs though.

Comment: I want URLS in my MYSQL to be hidden e.g. By not exposing the URL's in MYSQL LINK Table. Hope that clears up your minds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to make difference between two terms:

- Encoding
- Encryption

Encoding is the process of converting data with purposes as: transmitting, smaller size, standards and so on.
Encryption is the process of making your information only understandable for the receiver.

For those goals you can use either PHP functionality or build-in MySQL functions. Prefer MySQL if you're sure you'll stick with MySQL. You'd better prefer PHP if you want your application be more database-independent.

For PHP have a look here:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

For MySQL functions have a look here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html